# checking 2nd part of expression is an increment of the 1st

Tags: regex

Specifically, I'm looking to create a Reg Ex for a tax year in the format yyyy/yy where 2019/20 would correspond to the tax year of 06/04/2019 to 05/04/2020.

So the basic reg ex we have is `^2[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}$` which works to ensure the format is correct but will allow the likes of 2019-30 or 2019-18 etc when the only possible ending for 2019 is 20.

So does anyone know how I would validate that the section after the "/" was the last 2 digits of section 1 incremented by 1? If it was going to be 100% correct then this would also though have to take into account 2099/00 for 2099/2100.

So valid examples would include:
2001/02, 2002/03...2010/11, 2012/13, 2099/00 all the way through to 2999/00

Invalid would be anything where the 2 sections were not exactly +1 different so the likes of:
2010/12, 2100/10, 2010/09, 2019/19 etc

Any pointers for this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

file f1

```
2012/13
2012/02
2012/12
2199/00
2199/11
```

script f1.awk

```
match($1, /2[0-9]([0-9]{2})/, m) {
  if (($2 == m[1]+1) || (m[1] == 99 && $2 == "00")) {
    print($1"/"$2)
  } 
}
```

call:

```
gawk -F"/" -f f1.awk f1
```

result:

```
2012/13
2199/00
```

Explanation:

```
-F"/"     sets / as field separator
m[1]      is a reference to a group of 2 numbers set in regex
IF        checks the assumed condition 
          and takes into account the special case 99/00
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, apologies I missed it at the time. I think this probably answers my question as it was written however my question was probably poorly written. What I was looking for was a new regular expression that could be provided to users in order to ensure the data was in the correct format in the 1st place. So in other words I need to amend "^2[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}$" so that the vaidation is carried out in the expression.

Comment: As for me, many conditions for one regular expression and you don't mention anything in what programming language, but there are differences between them. AWK is perfect for such tasks.